# LTspice Color Palette

Tags: ltspice, color

In order to make my graphs printer friendly, I have made a color palette in LTspice that looks something like this:

[image]
[image]

1. How do I make this permanent? It keeps restoring to its default settings...
2. How do I increase the thickness of the plot for better visibility?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It should not. On my installation it's persistent. Do you have write permission in the LTspice user folder? You should have.
2. Under control panel -> wavefroms -> data trace width
   [image]

Comment: I cannot figure out the write permission. The changes are still temporary.

Comment: @courageouslywin What’s your LTspice user space app folder?

Comment: It is not in C: , but I configured it and disabled the read-only option in properties. It works now.